# Psycopg2 idle session timeout with ThreadedConnectionPool

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to setup ThreadedConnecionPool in my AWS Lambda, Postgres 14 is being used. The lambda might die abruptly and I want to make sure that the Postgres server closes the connection after 1 minute of idle activity, for example.

`idle_session_timeout` parameter states the following:

```
Be wary of enforcing this timeout on connections made through connection-pooling software or other middleware, as such a layer may not react well to unexpected connection closure. It may be helpful to enable this timeout only for interactive sessions, perhaps by applying it only to particular users.
```

Is PgBouncer the right answer here? Or is it safe to apply this setting in my case? Or is there a better approach? What I want to make sure is that the server does its own cleanup of connections created by the lambda ThreadedConnectionPool if it so happens the lambda died.

Comment: If the lambda does die, I would expect its end of the socket to get reaped by the OS.  For an idle connection, PostgreSQL should immediately become aware of this, and automatically close the connection.  I know lambdas are supposed to be some kind of "serverless" magic, but I would assume it is intended to be good magic, not evil magic.  Unless you have evidence to the contrary, I would assume these dying lambdas are a non-issue.

Comment: @jjanes I would expect to have the connections close, but when checking PgAdmin, there are a bunch of idle connections that eventually close. And the quantity and when they appear are not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you explicitly closing the connection when you are done with it?  If not and you just let the connection go out of scope, maybe the garbage collection system is just not very aggressive about cleaning it up.

Pgbouncer could be helpful for this, but it would have to be run in transaction pooling mode (because the default session pooling mode can't be very useful when the sessions don't get closed promptly), and that does impose some restrictions on what you can do, like prepared transactions.

Or, if you created a database user for your lambdas to use, then you could apply the idle timeout only to that user, and so prevent it from killing administrator, monitoring, or developer connections.  But combining the pooler and the timeout is probably not needed, or advisable.

Comment: Thanks,  I updated keepalives parameters in the parameter group used by RDS. Now if the lambda dies unexpectedly, all sessions are terminated after 30 seconds of no TCP acknowledgment from the client ( the Lambda in this case).